# php array to js array gives undefined variable on php arr exists and used multiple times before

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I know this is a duplicate but I can't find my answer between the answers on other questions, so please help.

I am trying to get a php array to a javascript array. My code editor (phpStorm) gives the error on the code that `$survey` is a undefined variable, my browser gives the same error in the console log except on the javascript file.

I have tried to `dd($survey)`, it exists and I use it all over my html file. I also have tried to json_encode the php array, gives the same errors.

dd($survey):

```
"data" => array:11 [
"id" => 2315
"name" => ""
"formFolderId" => 703
"createdAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
"updatedAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
"formCategories" => array:11 [
  0 => array:7 [
    "id" => 14048
    "name" => ""
    "formId" => 2315
    "createdAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
    "updatedAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
    "formQuestions" => array:4 [
      0 => array:26 [
        "id" => 158233
        "name" => ""
        "formCategoryId" => 14048
        "type" => "radio"
        "createdAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
        "updatedAt" => "2019-10-14 14:55:03"
        "formOptions" => array:6 []
]
]
```

My html head:

```
<script>
    let wholeSurvey = <?php $survey['data'] ?> ;
</script>
```

So I guess my question is how can I get `$survey` into wholeSurvey.

Sorry for grammar or spelling mistakes.

Comment: what is the purpose of putting the `$survay` to your `javascipt`

Comment: Because you've used it in JS.

Comment: @codeformoney To see if the user has answered all the questions

Comment: @AksenPWhat do you mean?

Comment: you should **never** mix PHP and JS - they're different languages that get executed differently. Use AJAX to pass variables back and forth - or if it's on within the same execution, assign the PHP value to a data-* tag and retrieve the value that way

Comment: Why not get this data using ajax? And as I could see you need to `json_encode()` the data into the variable.

Comment: Simply do `post`, `ajax` or `get` request and work with responded data as you wish. Also, this way of using will disable possibility to export JS files.

Comment: Does it count if $survey is already a get from a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
return view('view', compact('survey'));
```

your blade template:

```
const wholeSurvey = {!! json_encode($survey) !!},
```

Comment: Yea because `wholeSurvey` is an object

Comment: Thank you.
the return was not necessary but the blade template part was the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        let wholeSurvey = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($survey['data']); ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Gives error in console log:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: You don't need the JSON.parse here. You already become a valid JSON from json_encode.

Comment: Why would you use `JSON.parse()` in JS when `json_encode()` returns perfectly valid JSON to begin with? Just echo it (without wrapping it in quotes) and you're set.

Comment: After your edit it still gives a similar error in the console:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 244 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `echo`, also the json encode thingy:

```
const survey = <?php echo json_encode($survey["data"]);?>;
```

Comment: Tank you for your answer but this gives me the Array to string conversion error

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you're right. My bad, I updated the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use blade directive @json:

```
<script>
  let wholeSurvey = @json($survey['data']);
</script>
```